# select first match of condition XPATH

Tags: javascript, xpath

I have a xpath expression //*[@selected]/@value|//text().

I want first looking for "//*[@selected]/@value" and if elements doesn't exists looking for "//text()". My expression looking "//*[@selected]/@value" AND "//text()"

I mean i want to have code like this(javascript) but shorter because conditions could be more

```
function elementXpath(path) {
  return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}

var a = ''
if (elementXpath("[@selected]/@value") != null) a = elementXpath("[@selected]/@value")
else if (elementXpath("//text()") != null) a = elementXpath("//text()")
```

Answer (score 0):

First in document order? Then `(//*[@selected]/@value|//text())[1]` suffices.  Of course with Javascript both inside the browser and with Node.js there is SaxonJS supporting XPath 3.1 with sequences e.g. `(//*[@selected]/@value,//text())[1]`.